# Automatically refresh DHCP on wpa_supplicant (dis)connect (Debian 11)

Tags: debian, wifi, dhcp, wpa-supplicant

I have access to a Wifi SSID which works with the same credentials but it might access different access points with those credentials. This is a service by my provider that lets you connect to other customers modems who have this enabled, so there might be a couple modems nearby that all work with the same settings.

My `wpa_supplicant.conf` is a follows:

```
country=NL
network={
        ssid="Ziggo"
        identity="username"
        password="password"
        pairwise=CCMP
        group=CCMP
        scan_ssid=0
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        eap=PEAP
        ca_cert="/etc/wpa_supplicant/Ziggo.pem"
        phase1="peapver=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

This works to connect but I need to manually run `dhclient wlx14cc20254d5a` when it connects to get assigned an IP address.

However sometimes the connection will drop for a while and then reconnect but is no longer connective. I think this might happen when it switches to a different access point with the same SSID

When that happens I need to run `dhclient wlx14cc20254d5a -r && dhclient wlx14cc20254d5a` to make it connective again.

I tried adding the following to `/etc/network/interfaces` but it didn't help:

```
iface wlx14cc20254d5a inet dhcp
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Is there some way to automate this step: getting a lease on connect, and releasing it on disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

There is some option that may work for you. You can wait `wpa_supplicant` `DISCONNECT` event by running `wpa_cli` with `-a` option.

This allows to run a script whenever `CONNECTED`/`DISCONNECTED` event happens where you can run you `dhclient`.